# Why does my Webapp not work with Google's OAuth login system?

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin

I am attempting to build a basic Webapp which has a login with Google button. When the user logs in, I want the web app to change the 'login' button to change to a 'logout' button and also display the user's basic information such as their name which it obtains from their Google profile.

My site successfully opens the Google login page. I am able to click on my Google profile to login and am successfully redirected back to my site. However, nothing changes on my website. The login button still remains a login button and no information is displayed.

I want my site to display the user's information and also change the "login" button to a "logout" button.

I have ensured that my Authorised JavaScript origin (http://localhost:8000) and my Authorised redirect URL (http://localhost:8000/callback) is set correctly. I have also added my CLIENT_ID to my index file. I have also ensured that my client ID is correct.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <script>
      var googleUser;
      var profile;
      var auth2;

      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
        // Change the sign-in button to display the user's details
        document.getElementById("g-signin2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("user-details").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("user-name").innerHTML = profile.getName();
        document.getElementById("user-email").innerHTML = profile.getEmail();
        document.getElementById("user-image").src = profile.getImageUrl();
      }

      function signOut() {
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
          console.log('User signed out.');
          // Change the sign-in button back to the original state
          document.getElementById("g-signin2").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("user-details").style.display = "none";
        });
      }

      gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init({
          client_id: 'my-client-id is in here',
          redirect_url: 'http://localhost:8000/callback',
          scope: 'profile email'
        }).then(function(auth) {
            auth2 = auth;
            // Check if user is already signed in
            if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
              onSignIn(auth2.currentUser.get());
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style>
        .g-signin2 {
            width: auto;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #user-details {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" id="g-signin2"></div>
    <div id="user-details">
        <p id="user-name"></p>
        <button onclick="signOut()">Sign Out</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason your not using https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/automatic-sign-in-sign-out?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the debugger F12 most browsers you will find your code is throwing an error and a warning

[image]

> "You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead; existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."

There is really no reason for you to bother fixing this code it will stop working very soon. You should use the new [Web identity](https://developers.google.com/identity)

## code

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<script>
    function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
    console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
}
    window.onload = function () {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: "[REDACTED]",
        callback: handleCredentialResponse
    });
    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
    document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
{ theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
    );
    google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
}
</script>
<div id="buttonDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```